# Given a list of strings, is it feasible to get in one line a map from each length to the set of strings having that length, sorted by length?

Tags: java, java-stream, treemap, one-liner

I came up with the following, which does work, but I feel like there should be a cleaner one-line way that doesn't rely on an "outer" map (`result` below):

```
public TreeMap<Integer, HashSet<String>> mapLenToString(List<String> strings){
    TreeMap<Integer, HashSet<String>> result = new TreeMap<>();
    strings.stream()
           .forEach(s -> { 
                int len = s.length();
                if (result.containsKey(len)) {
                    HashSet<String> larger = result.get(len);
                    larger.add(s);
                    result.replace(len, larger);
                }
                else {
                    HashSet<String> newSet = new HashSet<>();
                    newSet.add(s);
                    result.put(len, newSet);
                }
                
            });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: By the way, is it absolutely necessary to have a `HashSet`?

Comment: @user Nope, just used it for the `larger.add(s)` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `groupingBy` collector. You can control the type of map and the type of set that the elements are collected into.

```
TreeMap<Integer, HashSet<String>> result = strs
  .stream()
  .collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
      s -> s.length(),
      TreeMap::new,
      Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)
    )
  );
```

Using this

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList(
  "DEF", "ABC", "Hello world", "z", 
  "a", "q", "90", "12345678910", "ab");
```

output is

```
{1=[a, q, z], 2=[90, ab], 3=[ABC, DEF], 11=[12345678910, Hello world]}
```

[Link to repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ThankfulFearfulVariety#Main.java)

---

You can also use `Collectors.toSet()` instead of `toCollection(HashSet::new)`, where the default implementation is `HashSet` (but probably not guaranteed to be so)

Comment: May I ask why this answer isn't correct? It seems to fit the OP's requirements (a `TreeMap<Integer, List<String>` sorted by the key.

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me, better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using Guava Multimaps:
[com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.index(iterable, function)](https://guava.dev/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-)-

```
Multimap<Integer, String> index =
       Multimaps.index(strs,  s -> s.length());
```

It's not sorted by the result, unfortunately.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to care about sorting the result anyways, so this should still be fine

Comment: But OP cares about having a sorted order of the keys, which `TreeMap` guarantees, and `Multimaps.index` does not.